# Is there any way to check the clipboard History without external app?

Tags: clipboard-manager

Is there anyway for me to look at the history of the contents of the clipboard?

I had a rather large SVN patch, that has unfortunately been wiped due to a careless copy of a URL, before pasting the contents of the patch. If I could recover those two hours of work, that would be very very nice.

And if not, are there any tools I can install to prevent such heinously stupid errors from occurring again?

Comment: So the answer to my original question is no then I guess. sigh

Comment: If you didn't had a clipboard manager, you are pretty much screwed up. Both of the links in comments could help you not to happen again... but I won't make promisses.